# How to create post favorite function without plugins

Tags: plugin-development

I'm developing a lesson plan plugin ... and within this lesson plans you will have the option to favorite which plans users like, I'm listing the registered plans this is very easy using as a shortcode like this below, but I've already looked for it until right here how to do it without using a plugin, but always ending up returned to install .... if you can help with examples or content it would help a lot, and I'm sorry for the bad writing in English[image]

Here is the code where I list the lesson plans

```
 function lesson_plans(){

    $cale_plan_post = [
        'post_type'      => 'cale-plan',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
       
    ];
    
   $cale_plan_posts  = new WP_Query( $cale_plan_post);
    while (  $cale_plan_posts->have_posts() ) :  
        $cale_plan_posts->the_post(); 
        echo'<div>
                <div class="">
                    <h2>'; echo the_title().'</h2>';
                    echo the_content().'
                    <a href='; echo the_permalink (). '>zz</a>
                </div>
                
                <a  data-post-id="';echo $cale_plan_posts->post->ID. '">♥ Add to favorites</a>
            </div>';
          
       
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

if ( class_exists( 'Cale_discourse' ) ) {
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, [ 'Cale_discourse', 'activate' ] );
    register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, [ 'Cale_discourse', 'deactivate' ] );
    register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, [ 'Cale_discourse', 'uninstall' ] );
    add_shortcode( 'list_plans' ,'lesson_plans');
  
    $cale_discourse = new GlobalCale_discourse();     
    
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/234990/favouriting-a-custom-post-type

This is untested, but it did answer their question on how to accomplish this. Not posting as an answer for this reason.

Comment: I took a look at what you indicated but I noticed that it doesn't explain this function, could you tell me ( is_added_to_favorite)?

Answer (score 1):

thanks Lisa Cerilli, for the link I gave you a base on how to do it... I made some adjustments... but it helped a lot, follow my answer

**in the front html it was like this/ php :here I list the post and the link to favorite**

```
<?php while ( $list_plans->have_posts() ) :  ?>
    <?php  $list_plans->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="services__item  ">
            <div class="services__description">
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink (); ?>">Saiba mais</a>
                <span class="add-to-fav">
                    <?php 
                        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
                        $property_id = get_the_ID();
                        if(is_added_to_favorite( $user_id ,$property_id)) {
                            ?>
                                <div class="fav-output show">
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>&nbsp;
                                    <span class="fav-target">Added to Favourites</span>
                                </div>
                        <?php
                        } else {
                        ?>
                        <a href="#add-to-favorite"  id="post-<?php echo $property_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $property_id; ?>" class="add-to-favorite">
                            <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>&nbsp;
                            <span id="<?php echo $property_id; ?>" class="<?php echo $user_id; ?>">Add to Favourites</span>
                        </a>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>   
<?php endwhile;?>
```

**and here is the javascript to get the post and user id by ajax**

```
<script  >  
  jQuery(function ($) {
    var property_id  ;
    var user_id  ;
    const favorite = (property_id , user_id) => {
    $.ajax({
                url: ajaxUrl,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'add_to_favorite',   
                    property_id,
                    user_id
                },
                }).done((response) => {
                    var property_id =null;
                        
                    })  
         
            
    };  
    $("a.add-to-favorite").find("span").click(function(){
        var property_id =   $(this).attr("id");
        var  user_id =    $(this).attr("class");
     favorite(property_id, user_id );
   }); 
  
});


</script>
```

and in functions.php I put the functions

```
 function is_added_to_favorite( $user_id, $property_id ){
        global $wpdb;
     
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key='favorite_properties' AND meta_value=".$property_id." AND user_id=". $user_id );
      
        if( isset($results[0]->meta_value) && ($results[0]->meta_value == $property_id) ){
            return true;
          
        }else{
            return false;
          
        }
    }


//ignora isto e so teste

    function add_to_favorite(){
        if( isset($_POST['property_id']) && isset($_POST['user_id']) ){
            $property_id = intval($_POST['property_id']);
            $user_id = intval($_POST['user_id']);
          
            if( $property_id > 0 && $user_id > 0 ){
                if( add_user_meta($user_id,'favorite_properties', $property_id ) ){
                    _e('Added to Favorites', 'framework');
                }else{
                    _e('Failed!', 'framework');
                }
            }
        }else{
            _e('Invalid Paramenters!', 'framework');
        }
        die;
    }

add_action('wp_ajax_add_to_favorite', 'add_to_favorite');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_to_favorite', 'add_to_favorite' );
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Sorry I didn't get a chance to test it for you and post an actual answer.